# Python option parser overwrite '-h'

Tags: python, elf

I have the following options

```
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-a', '--all', action='store_true', dest='all', help='writes all header information')
parser.add_option('-h', '--file-header', action='store_true', dest='head',  help='prints the elf file header information')
parser.add_option('-l', '--program-header', action='store_true', dest='prog',  help='prints the program header')
parser.add_option('-S', '--section-header', action='store_true', dest='sec',  help='prints the section header')
```

When running the script I get the error message:

```
 optparse.OptionConflictError: option -h/--file-header: conflicting option string(s): -h
```

I know normally -h is reserved to display the help. But I'm trying to write an ELF file reader for some special elf files, and therefore I want to use the same commands like `readelf`. And readelf uses -h for printing the header information.

Is there any possibility to overwrite the -h option in the option parser or is that fixed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When creating the parser, pass `add_help_option=False`. Then you will be able to define it by yourself:

```
parser =  OptionParser(add_help_option=False)
```